Does Jakarta ee 10 and EJB specifications are inconsistently?
I am migrating from JEE 8 to Jakarta 10 .
I read on JakartaEE 10 spec that Embeddable EJB Container was removed and there is a reference to Jakarta Enterprise Beans 4.0 describing the usefull feature of Embeddable EJB Contanier , the there is a mistake ?
Jakarta Enterprise Beans 4.0 was created for Jakarta EE 9 I suppose, then were is the EJB spec related to Jakarta EE 10 ?

(1) You can download examples from the URL: Jakarta EE 10 Examples(https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jakartaee-examples) (2) download zip(https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jakartaee-examples/archive/refs/heads/main.zip) (3) unzip zip file (4) find out tutorial/ejb, run exmaple code first. (5) You can ignore Embeddable EJB Contanier topic. (6) EJB 4.0 Spec is related to Jakarta EE 10, only remove 2 topic ((A) Entity Beans, both Container and Bean Managed Persistence (B) Embeddable EJB Container)

https://docs.wildfly.org/32/Getting_Started_Guide.html#getting-started-with-wildfly , Jakarta Enterprise Beans 4.0 X X(Lite) X X(Lite)

what mean whit "(5) You can ignore Embeddable EJB Contanier" ? 1. Embeddable Container is removed in EE 10 , ok ?  2. EE10-EJB version 4.0 , ok ? if these points are true , then why EJB spec 4.0 have a pharagraf 17 , telling about Embeddable :                 EJBContainer ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();

life888888, ok the main info useful for me is  EmbeddableEJBContainer was removed in JEE 10 , but on this page "https://jakarta.ee/specifications/enterprise-beans/4.0/" but I got a mistake because on this page it is states " Jakarta Enterprise Beans 4.0
Release for Jakarta EE 9"   ,this generated my doubt .     anyway someone can answer : what would be an equivalent to EmbeddableEJBContainer ; I sued it to test my EJB project before to assembly the EAR

(1) When I run into a problem with a version of a spec, I go back to the simplest test: write a test on that topic. (2) If I don't know where to start, (2a) I look for Sample programs that comply with a certain specification (Jakarta EE 10). (https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jakartaee-examples) (2b) I will also look for which AP Server applies that specification (Jakarta EE 10) , Wildfly 27, 28,...33. Then I will try to find if there is a sample program for Wildfly 27 or 33 (https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/33.x), and then find the corresponding Sample program for theme (EJB).
